# Transaction error on XHCI setAddress command for a bare-metal USB driver

Tags: usb

I'm trying to implement a bare metal xhci driver for a TI Sitara processor (based on dwc3 ip).

I can address it for a few devices (like mass storage and a mouse) but it fails on almost all other devices. if I do BSR = 1 it's successful but then if I want to read descriptors or set with BSR = 0, it fails on all devices except the ones I mentioned. it's so frustrating.

for the Mass storage and mouse that it works, i'm capable of reading its descritpor and its correct.

I do this : attachDetect -> Reset Roothub (cause USB2) -> Enable Slot -> Set Address -> (if not fail) get Descriptors

I've tried, 1000 different combination of delay functions between my commands hoping that would solve my problem but nothing.

I've also tried disableSlot command on the transaction error and start over but same thing happens.

Also, I have on port only (MAXPortNum = 1 in capability register).

Also, despite being an XHCI controller, it only supports USB2. no USB3 capabilities.

I will open source my code when finished, so please help me figure this out. been on this for a month and TI won't help with bare metal USB queries.